# Unable to get just one key at a time from the node "History"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```html
{
  "History" : {
    "-LIRZ4Nf2HyTTYtZEeOA" : {
      "destination" : "101 Main Street, Your Town, Your Country",
      "driver" : "vP9r4F2yDWRRuvKjRiQvMEXVuoK2",
      "payment response" : "approved",
      "rating" : 0,
      "ridePrice" : 3.63,
      "rider" : "C0RjB5NPZcTvWz9XiUAhpTDOK0C2",
      "status" : "accepted",
      "timestamp" : 1532709012
    }
  }
```

The above is the History node in my Firebase database.

My ultimate goal is to send an alert dialog once the *payment response = "approved"* but, in this case, when there is more than one key in the History node, the alerts run on top of each other.

What can I do so this does not happen?

The code I am using to get the key for each History entry is:

```
private void getPaymentResponse() {
    final DatabaseReference paymentConfirmed = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History");
    paymentConfirmed.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ryydeKey = ds.getKey(); **<-- gets the key**

                DatabaseReference response = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("History")
                        .child(ryydeKey);
                response.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (child.getKey().equals("payment response")) {
                                String response = String.valueOf(child.getValue().toString());
                                if (response.equals("approved")) {
                                    proceedToPickupDialog();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am assuming that the code:

```
 for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     ryydeKey = ds.getKey();
```

is getting all the keys, but all I want is the present key.

### Edit

I am putting in this code and nothing is printing up.  Tried logs and toasts.

```
DatabaseReference payRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = payRef.child("History").orderByChild("driver").equalTo(driverId).limitToLast(1);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String response = ds.child("payment response").getValue(String.class);
                Log.e(TAG, "response = " + response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `getChildren()` method, it means that you are looping through the entire `DataSnapshot` object. If the DataSnapshot contains more then one child, then the alerts will run on top of each other. If you want to check only for a particular child, you need to change the code a little bit.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child("History").child("-LIRZ4Nf2HyTTYtZEeOA");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String response = dataSnapshot.child("payment response").getValue(String.class);
        if(response.equalTo("approved")) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Payment approved!");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Payment not approved!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
idRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Using this code, you get only the response form a single child. To actually get this work done, first you need to store this value `-LIRZ4Nf2HyTTYtZEeOA` in a variable in order to be able to use in your reference.

**Edit:** This another approach using a query"

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("History").orderByChild("driver").equalsTo(driverId).limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String response = dataSnapshot.child("payment response").getValue(String.class);
            if(response.equalTo("approved")) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Payment approved!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177050/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-mamo-unable-to-get-just-one-key-at-a-time-from-the).

Comment: With the help of the code provided above, and moving the call to a later method, it works!